# Navigating jumplist in Vim with Tab mapped elsewhere

Tags: vim

I've mapped the `<Tab>` key to switch buffers. However, as `<Tab>` is equivalent to `<Ctrl-I>`, I'm unable to navigate the jumplist.

Is there any way to map the jumplist navigation to some other key (say `g,` and `g.` for example) such that I can use `<Tab>` independently?

Comment: Realise that `g,` already exists as a change list forward jump (you're proposing to replace it with a jump list backward jump). Naturally, once you've realised it, you're welcome to ignore it. I've certainly never used `g,` or `g;`; the jump list operations tend to be good enough.

Comment: Chris, I'm aware of that. Actually, I'm using `g;` and `g'` to navigate the changelist because it is more intuitive as they are beside each other.

Comment: So now you're shadowing `g'` as well ;-)

Comment: Does `g'` do anything useful?

Comment: See `:help g'`. I can't say that I would ever expect to use it. `'` by itself is all I would ever want (or rather `\``, I can't think of any time I use `'` instead.)

Comment: Oh, didn't know about `g'`. Same here, can't think where I'd use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,  just use `nore` when defining the maps.

```
nnoremap g, <C-o>
nnoremap g. <C-i>
```

The `nore` tells vim to not respect maps in the right hand side of the mapping.

Comment: Damn, I'd forgotten about noremaps in search for something complicated.